# One form inside another one form

Tags: html

I have one Form which have one submit button let us name this as FORM 1 and inside that form I have another form with one submit button and this form name is FORM 2. Now my problem is When i am clicking submit button of FORM 2, FORM 2 submit button is using an action of FORM 1 which i don't want. I know its sounds confusion but check the codes you will come to know :

```html
<form action="pks.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="mob">
<input type="text" name="opr">
<form action="pksa.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="opra">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

I am trying something like to achieve but i am not able to Please help me out

Comment: It does not make any sense having a form inside another. Review you design

Answer (score 0):

> I have one Form which have one submit button let us name this as FORM
>   1 and inside that form I have another form with one submit button and
>   this form name is FORM 2.

In HTML you cannot nest `<form>` elements. This simply results in invalid markup and undefined behavior. You will have to reorganize your markup in a way that doesn't involve nested forms.

Comment: I have one form  with some input text and one link(For ex <a href"xyz.php> . Now i want the value to be passed with this link to xyz.php?mob=789&pks=123 like this and this values are of the input text of the same form. I hope you got what i am trying to achieve can you help me out.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve and how does this relate to your nested forms issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested forms. Browsers won't allow that. Actually if you inspect the form in browser developer tools, you will see that child forms are removed.

Comment: I have one form  with some input text and one link(For ex <a href"xyz.php> . Now i want the value to be passed with this link to xyz.php?mob=789&pks=123 like this and this values are of the input text of the same form. I hope you got what i am trying to achieve can you help me out.